# Joomla - get specific module from article id

Tags: php, joomla, module

Very simple question - but I can't seem to find an answer here og by looking at the structure of the Joomla database.

How can I get a specific module (through the position-field) from the article-id that the module is assigned to?

The situation is that I need to extract a number of Joomla articles and for each article I need to find the content of a module with a particular position-value.

How is that done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can't get it. When creating custom module you never dictate which articles(or something else) are u going to select from database in module.

Comment: This is issue is a bit odd but I think you can. For example, you can override the content component to do that. Otherwise, you can use css to hide or show any modules (but the module is loaded anyway).

Comment: I think you can map the article assigned to particular menu id and the module assigned to the same. Please note that this is not the perfect solution what you need to change approach.

Comment: Yes, maybe I need to go through the menu-id since the module is assigned to the menu. Could that work? Thanks.